# How can I pass multiple CSV files in a directory with same column headers to single REST API in JMETER and test with 1000 users

Tags: csv, jmeter, performance-testing

Test scenario: The folder contains multiple CSVs. Columns are same in all the CSVs.I have to pass multiple csv files one after the other to the single REST API (GET CALL).

Each user (Total 1000 users) should get assigned a set of records/rows from csv file currently in use.

I am new to the JMeter and finding a solution using the CSV Data Set Config. And I realize I could not pass multiple csv files using this.

I also see that __CSVRead() function but I could not pass dynamically the csv file using BeanShell scripting.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. The CSV file names from the folder can be read one by one using [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter/) plugin
2. Depending on the CSV file nature you might want to use either [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) functions directly in your HTTP Request sampler, you don't need to go for any scripting.

Comment: File nature is Pipe delimited and some column headers may be null that I need to ingest before using the data in it. And the rows in a file can go up to 6-8 million records. Would you recommend using __CSVRead() function to handle this data